# Update data in firebase using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem, I am sending data every minute to a firebase 
 database in a cron tab that is running in nodejs, I only send the information when there are changes, but when there are no changes the database continues to receive information, This is my code

```
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
let prev_res = {};

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'mydburl'
});

cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'myhost',
      user     : 'myuser',
      password : 'mypass',
      database : 'mydb'
    });

    connection.query("MY QUERY", function(err, rows, fields){
        if (!err){
            if(JSON.stringify(rows) != JSON.stringify(prev_res)){
                let db = admin.database();
                let ref = db.ref('path');
                ref.set(rows);

                console.log("Updated data");
            } else {
                console.log("without changes");
            }

            prev_res = rows;

        }
    });

});
```

Does the firebase admin have some kind of cache or something like that?

Comment: If firebase receives data, that mean the if condition is failing. So, you should check the code.

Comment: In the console it shows the message "without changes", I suppose that the condition is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a strange problem with Firebase Authentication. 
The issue resides in the permissions for the user you are including in your credentials.
Besides creating a **Service Account** with the correct permissions, you need to add this user to your **IAM Accounts** with the **editor** role.

Restart your App after doing this and you should stop seeing:

> "FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid.
>   This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized
>   correctly."